# Repair Windows 7 Start Disk from a Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, hard-drive, boot, repair

I have a hard drive from a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Windows 7 which seems to have a corrupted boot disk that I'm trying to repair. The laptop won't boot (freezes on black screen after Windows logo), and isn't running the built-in repair utility (same issue; freezes on boot).

I tried booting from a repair disc and running the startup repair utility, but after four days the repair was only at 5% complete, so I decided to look for another solution. I removed the HDD and attached it to an enclosure. When I connected to it through my Windows 7 laptop, I could see the drive listed, but explorer froze when trying to access the drive. Next I connected to my MacBook and everything seems to be working (I can see the drive contents and recover the files).

I'm wondering if there is any way to perform a Windows 7 startup repair on the drive from my MacBook Pro. Some Googling didn't turn up any obvious utilities that might help, and obviously if this is not possible I can just back up the data and reformat, but if there is an easy fix that would save me some time I would love to check it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your drive is having bad sectors. Have you tried to make a boot USB disk with Linux, (say Ubuntu) and have a look at the SMART DATA (disk utility) to see if your windows is corrupt in essential files?

Comment: Good idea! Could I check the SMART DATA if I connect the drive to a laptop running Ubuntu, or do I need to boot from a USB? I have a netbook running Ubuntu that I could use if I can. I will give it a shot once I finish backing up the data.

Comment: I' not 100% sure but I think USB bus doesn't support SMART DATA. Since you probably have the disk on a USB Case you could try.